# How to get value of $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $a+b+c=0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=36$, what is the value of $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(a+b+c)=0\implies (a+b+c)^2=0 $$
$$\implies a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)=0$$
$$\implies 36+2(ab+bc+ca)=0$$
$$\implies (ab+bc+ca)=-18$$
$$\implies (ab+bc+ca)^2=324$$

just solve this whole square you can find answer

$$\implies a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+2(ab^2c+bc^2a+a^2bc)=324$$
$$\implies a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2+2abc(b+c+a)=324$$
since $a+b+c=0$

so
$$\implies a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2=324$$

Answer (score 5):

We'll work with what we have until we get what we want:

$$0 = (a + b + c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2ab + 2bc + 2 ac = 36 + 2(ab + bc + ac)$$
And therefore we can conclude that
$$
 - 18 = ab + bc + ac
$$
This in turn means that
$$
324 = (ab + bc + ac) ^2  = a^2b^2 + b^2 c^2 + a^2 c^2 + 2(a^2bc + ab^2 c + abc^2) \\\\
=a^2b^2 + b^2 c^2 + a^2 c^2 + 2abc(a + b + c) = a^2b^2 + b^2 c^2 + a^2 c^2 + 0$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I haven't, but it's multiplied with $(a + b + c) = 0$